# Find the limit of this sequence: $x_{n}= \sum_{0}^{n} (-1)^k \binom{\frac{-1}{2}} {k} 3^{k} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am studying a book on introduction to functional analysis and I came across this exercise.  I have been thinking about it for a while but I don't know how to tackle it. Can you please show me a solution to this problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, I had some trouble typesetting the formula but now It's fixed. I need some help with this, please!

Comment: Doesn't look like that is going to converge.

Comment: What's your reasoning @DougM?

Comment: Work out the first few terms.  Then look for a rule for then n+1 th term based on its predecessor.  Sonething like...  $a_{n+1} = a_n\frac {(-\frac 12 + n)}{n+1}3.$  Then apply the ratio test.

Comment: I would call its limit $(1-3)^{-1/2}$

Comment: @plop How come you get a pure imaginary as the sum of a series of real numbers?

Comment: @DougL It is a joke, [partly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)